# "Insufficient privileges" when querying the overage claim URI in AAD multi-tenant app

Tags: c#, permissions, multi-tenant, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity

I have a multi-tenant AAD app in tenant A that accepts tokens issued by tenant B to authenticate its users. The permissions that the app requests are set to the default lowest level - read basic user's profile.

When the user (non-admin) from tenant B logs in, I see the claims, and I've configured the app to send user's group in claims as well. Inside of the group claim, instead of the groups list I am seeing "**src1**" reference, implying that the user is a member of over 200 groups and that I need to query that URI to get the list of those groups.

When I query that URI, however, I get back an "**Insufficient privileges**" error. I'm actually able to query "/me" URI just fine for the user and see his direct manager and even the office location, but I'm not able to see his or her security groups.

Are the group claims included in what I'm allowed to read when the user consented to be authenticated by my app, or it's something only an admin can consent to? If I am indeed supposed to see them, what is the right way to access them given the overage claim URI?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: 
More info about the code:
I was using a book (not a specific tutorial), and my code lives in *AuthorizationCodeReceived* notification body, and looks like this:

```
var ClientId = "...";
// Notice the "common"
var Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
var appKey = "...";
var resourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";
var code = context.Code;
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);
var credential = new ClientCredential(ClientId, appKey);
var result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, resourceId);

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

// I'm not very sure about this part - I tried different ways, but all request that "work" result in "Insufficient privileges"
var p = new { securityEnabledOnly = true };
string postBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); 

var response = httpClient.PostAsync("<the src1 url>", new StringContent(postBody, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
```

Comment: If your access token from Tenant B, you only query groups in Tenant B. And your app's `Permissions to other applications` need to set permission. what tutorial did you follow? I want to check if you miss something...

Comment: Added more info on the exact code - though I've tried different ways of getting the groups. I tried doing GET on getMemberGroups and getMemberObjects (the latter was originally referenced in the src1 url), but the result is always the same - Insufficient privileges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I can answer my own question. It turns out that User.Read includes only the "Declared" properties of the User entity, while the group membership is a Navigation property.

To get access to the group, I need to request Group.Read.All permission, which requires Admin consent.

Here is the documentation on permission:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes

And here is the description of entities:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#userentity

It's all in the docs, just need to be very attentive to details when reading.

Answer (score 0):

Add：I run your code without error, make sure your web app has permission to access Graph Api. Below is the code, I simplify someplace.

```
        var ClientId = "***";
        // Notice the "common"
        var Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid";
        var appKey = "k***";
        var resourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";
       // var code = context.Code;
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);
        var credential = new ClientCredential(ClientId, appKey);
        var result = authContext.AcquireToken(resourceId,credential);

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

        // I'm not very sure about this part - I tried different ways, but all request that "work" result in "Insufficient privileges"
       // var p = new { securityEnabledOnly = true };
      //  string postBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var   result1 = httpClient.GetAsync("https://graph.windows.net/tenantid/users?api-version=1.6").Result;

        var  jsonresult=result1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: What permissions did your app request? Did you also get an src1 URL for groups? I see that you access the user profile, not groups